# crash: invalid structure member offset: kmem_cache_s_num FILE: memory.c LINE: 9619 FUNCTION: kmem_cache_init()

Tags: linux, crash, kernel, crash-dumps, panic

I'm learning linux kernel dev. Very new to it. I'm playing around with kernel panic.

my os version:

```
pegasus@pegasusv:~$ uname -a
Linux pegasusv 5.19.0-41-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Apr 17 19:17:03 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm on QEMU/KVM.
Command I've run to cause the panic:

```
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Before running it I'd configured everything properly.
I'm following this link:
I'd also downloaded all the dbg-sym images of the same kernel.

> https://ruffell.nz/programming/writeups/2019/02/22/beginning-kernel-crash-debugging-on-ubuntu-18-10.html

But when I'm rebooting using the same kernel, and running **crash** I'm getting the following error:

```
pegasus@pegasusv:/usr/lib/debug/boot$ crash vmlinux-5.19.0-41-generic /var/crash/202305100142/dump.202305100142 

crash 8.0.0
Copyright (C) 2002-2021  Red Hat, Inc.
Copyright (C) 2004, 2005, 2006, 2010  IBM Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999-2006  Hewlett-Packard Co
Copyright (C) 2005, 2006, 2011, 2012  Fujitsu Limited
Copyright (C) 2006, 2007  VA Linux Systems Japan K.K.
Copyright (C) 2005, 2011, 2020-2021  NEC Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999, 2002, 2007  Silicon Graphics, Inc.
Copyright (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002  Mission Critical Linux, Inc.
Copyright (C) 2015, 2021  VMware, Inc.
This program is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License,
and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under
certain conditions.  Enter "help copying" to see the conditions.
This program has absolutely no warranty.  Enter "help warranty" for details.
 
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.2                             
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...

please wait... (gathering kmem slab cache data)
crash: invalid structure member offset: kmem_cache_s_num
       FILE: memory.c  LINE: 9619  FUNCTION: kmem_cache_init()

[/usr/bin/crash] error trace: 56207d0cb69e => 56207d09f2f4 => 56207d16d11b => 56207d16d09c
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Known issue that has been fixed upstream in [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2041702).  I found your kmem_cache_s_num error message in [this github changelog](https://crash-utility.github.io/crash.changelog.html) for **crash-utility** under the 4.0-2.12 release notes.  You just need to find the best way to consume this crash(8) update in your Ubuntu environment; you can either find an Ubuntu-packaged binary or build from the source in the github repo.

Best of luck with your fix and continued development!

Comment: Canonical hasn't bumped crash utility despite they bumped Ubuntu kernel to 6.2: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/crash/+bug/2012060